# What causes raw TeX code to appear on Questions page but not on question's own page?

Tags: discussion

I was just curios about occasional occurrences [such as this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276643/continuity-of-a-function-with-2-variables) where raw TeX code shows up in the description of the problem on Questions page (but not in the page for the question itself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preview consists of $n$ characters.

If the MathJax code begins within these $n$ characters, but does not terminate within that limit, the site won't compile it.